# Get secret string value stored in AWS Parameterstore or in AWS SecretsManager in an SSM Document

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I have tried to find some answer to this question on the internet, but I could not find anything anywhere.

I know that it is possible to retrieve secrets from AWS Parameterstore or AWS SecretsManager
using Cloudformation. Is it possible to do the same using a SSM Document? Like for example to load the information of an API Key into an SSM Document dynamically from AWS Parameterstore or AWS SecretsManager?

If that is possible, what options do I have to pass the parameters from AWS Parameterstore or AWS SecretsManager to an SSM Document?

If possible a small coding example would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic references to specify values to cloudformation template, but for secure parameter store it is limited to some AWS resources(I don't think ssm document is supported), you can see the details here: [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html)

Comment: Yes, this works for Cloudformation indeed. I have found this source where the Author apparently somehow uses a SecretsManager value as an input for a SSM Document or do I misunderstand this?

https://medium.com/@dnorth98/curated-aws-ssm-scripts-ad68389f55c0

Comment: I have found this here, apparently it is not possible to use SecureString with SSM Documents ... https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-systems-manager-user-guide/issues/55
Is there any other good way to pass an encrypted API Key to a SSM Document in some way?